# How to search package in ADT?

Tags: abap, abap-adt

After installing the Eclipse ADT I created the ABAP package in cloud system, and I can't find that package in the `ZLOCAL` parent package to put it on my Favorite Packages.

How can I find it?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl-Shift-A and you will be showed a search popup where you can type the name of your package:

[image]